# How to use parellex for html form

Tags: html, css

I am going to use parellex in my web application.I have check below link. Its working fine as per my requirement.I would like to know how to use html form instead of background image in parellex css class.

For example :

I have two div ,first div contain html form with input field and second div contain hrml Table with data.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax_device

Comment: First of all its hard to understand what you want to achieve and secondly the above effect is applied to background through ```div{background-position:fixed}``` property. So,maybe it wont work the way you want it to work because then the form will be fixed in  the background, but still, I don't understand what your goals are as there is no reusable code....

Comment: does this help you: [CSS only parallax effect](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/)

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can achive this by setting the `postion` of the element to `fixed` and then set the `z-index` to anything, so that the element is always behind!

```css
body, html { height: 100%; font-family: sans-serif; }

.form {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vw;
  z-index: -9999;
}

.redDiv {
  height:100vh;
  margin: 150px auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color:red;
  font-size:36px
}
```

```html
<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<form class="form">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div class="redDiv">
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
</div>
```

Comment: down-voted for missing explaination. Code only answers are considered low-quality as they are hard to understand and as such to reproduce.

Comment: Okay thanks for that, i'll try to improve that

Comment: revoked the down-vote as the explainationw as added. However IMO the explaination could add more clarity e.g. that you need to add a negative z-index not just any z-index.